# Customizable Folderbrowserdialog c#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, custom-controls

I want to change the appearance of the regular folderbrowserdialog, as i have my application and i don't want to show the dialog with its default appearance, can anyone help me to find a control that is customizable (i.e Colors of the background and fonts),and for free:)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [this component](http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm)?

It appears to allow customization:

[image: Customized Dialog]

It says it supports both WinForms and WPF.

Comment: Thanks Nick but i think it's not for free :D :D

Comment: @Sara you should specify you're only looking for free components.